# ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file help meeee

Tags: mysql, macos, osx-yosemite, pid

Trying to get MySQL server working on my macbook pro, but get the following error.

> ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file

I have tried the following:

1. Deleting .err files
2. Change owner of mysql map to _mysql:_mysql
3. Change all rights to 777

and many more but nothing helpes.

First I installed MySQL via the original MySQL installer from the website. Later I did a brew install and it worked after brew was finished.

I use the following commands to start mysql:

```
sudo mysql.server start
sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server start
```

It worked yesterday, I restarted mac and it gave me this error.

Comment: Do you have any more detailed output, such as in a log file?  What command(s) are you using to start MySQL?  How is it installed (e.g., Homebrew, compiled sources or some Mac package installer)?

Comment: If you've already changed permissions and configs, can you get it back to a known (possibly broken) state?  It may be tough to fix after a lot of attempts that changed the wrong things...

Comment: Please see my edited question. I first installed buy installer and did later a brew install. thx.

Comment: You need to read MySQL log. Seriously. If you make random changes you'll just break it beyond any possible recovery.

Comment: Thank you for your reaction. I tried to reed "Gazars-MacBook-Pro.local.err"  with vim. It opened, but it says [Permission Denied] on the bottom next to the file name. Is it possible some permissions are not right?

Comment: All files in /usr/local/var/mysql have the following owners Gazar:_mysql, but the .err files have _mysql:_mysql